# VB Script Set Statement

Tags: vbscript, error-handling, set

I need help with the following codes:

```
Dim IE 
Dim UserName

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://www.nextview.com/index.php?country=my"
Do Until IE.ReadyState <> 3
Loop

Set UserName = IE.Document.getElementById("username")     <----- ERROR
IE.Document.all.UserName.Value = "TESTING"
Set Login = IE.Document.getElementById("frmlogin")
Login.submit
Do Until IE.ReadyState <> 3
Loop
```

The codes are created to help me key in my username. But it has error at the location shown above.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: What has this to do with VB.NET ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your waiting `Do..Loop` is not correct.

```
'Syntax notes:
Do Until [expression return False]
Do While [expression return True]

'So, you can use one of the next:
Do Until IE.readyState = 4
    Wscript.Sleep 100
Loop

Do While IE.readyState <> 4
    Wscript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

Comment: Either that or `While IE.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - There no `Exit` for `While..Wend` therefore I can't remember when I used it for a last time, but yes, it's applicable here, thanks for the addition.